# Быстрая перезагрузка в ring-0

Tags: ассемблер, masm32

Пишу драйвер на MASM для Windows NT. Необходимо реализовать мгновенную перезагрузку либо выключение. Вариант с записью в порты не подходит ввиду неуниверсальности (не на всех чипсетах работает), на многих компьютерах выбрасывает в BSOD с ошибкой PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA. Подскажите, имеются ли в Windows NT и выше функции, которые помогут мне реализовать подобную вещь?

Comment: Вы ведь понимаете, что выполнять немедленное завершение работы системы опасно? Хотя бы потому, что файловая система может остаться в неопределённом состоянии и потребует проверки и восстановления.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прочтите [этот лист](http://www.osronline.com/showThread.cfm?link=90397), тут всё написано об этом, если только вы уверены, что это то, что вам действительно нужно.

Comment: cy6erGn0m, огромное спасибо, документ указал в нужном направлении. Касательно риска такого завершения работы: я понимаю опасности, которые могут возникнуть, но поставленная задача вынуждает принимать их.